# Is it possible to change widgets in QGIS when opening style-file with Python

Tags: qgis, python, qml

When loading a QGIS-project using a Python-file and having the same name on both shp- and qml-file, just the symbology and labels are according to the style-file, but not the widgets.

I have tried 2 methods:

1. Use load.py to load a QGIS-project and add 1457_skrot.shp. 1457_skrot.**qml** is stored in the same folder as 1457_skrot.shp.

   > `python load_proj.py C:\kmfelt\shape\utm32\2017\1457_skrot.shp`
2. Use test_style.py to load a QGIS-project and to add both the shp-file and the qml-file in the py-file.

   > `python test_style.py`

Code within the test_style.py:

```
vfile = r"C:\\kmfelt\\shape\\utm32\\2017\\1457_skrot.shp"
vlayer_name = os.path.split(vfile)[1]
print vfile
print vlayer_name
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(vfile, vlayer_name, "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print "Vector layer "+vlayer+" failed to load!"
vlayer.loadNamedStyle('C:\\kmfelt\\shape\\utm32\\2017\\1457_skrot.qml')
vlayer.triggerRepaint()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([vlayer], True)
```

In both cases just the symbols (color, size) and labels are set according to the style-file. However, all the widgets are set to Text edit and NOT to the specific widgets set in the style-file.
[image]

But, if I load the style-file manually (click Style - Load Style), the widgets change:
[image]

Is it possible to achieve the same effect (including change in widgets) using Python? (I'm using QGIS 2.18.6.)